# Cannot Update-Database with EF in .NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, .net-core

I am using a PostgreSQL database and the NpgSQL package for Entity Framework. I have made some changes in my model and now am trying to migrate the database. However, after entering:

```
PM> Update-Database -verbose
```

I get:

```
Using framework 'netcoreapp1.0'
Using data directory 'D:\GIT\foo\Foo\src\Foo.WebApp\.\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0'
Build started...
Build failed.
```

I have [found in a github thread](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3925)  that I should use `dotnet build` to discover the build errors. However, the build is successful. Is there any other way to resolve what is preventing my database from being updated?

Comment: how about migration configuration file ... is it showing all changes correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, but simply switched to the command line, and everything worked. (I still can't explain the error in the Package Manager Console.)

From Windows PowerShell:

```
PS C:\{Proj folder}> dotnet ef database update
```